# Download by exporting uri without browser dependency

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, web-services, export-to-excel

I used common approach to export html table into excel sheet are following:

```
var tableToExcel = function () {
     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></br></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

     return function (data, name) {
         var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: data }
         var url = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
         return url;
     }
}()
```

Now i want to save the excel file in my local drive without using browser. I have tried the following approach

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "ImageSaving.asmx/SaveFile",
     data: JSON.stringify({ url: url }),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'json'
});
```

And on the server:

```
public string SaveFile(string url)
{
    try 
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string s = e.ToString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

But it throws exception that uri formate  is not correct. when hit the uri by browser it works fine. but i want to save it by code without browser dependency.

Answer (score 0):

1) WebClient connect to server by https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC822539.jpg
2) WebClient save file(it will create or rewrite) on C drive

Example:

```
WebClient download = new WebClient();
download.DownloadFile("https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC822539.jpg", "C:/Users/<UserName>/img.jpg");
```

WebClient need a protocol prefix: http:// https:// ftp://